# iOS Swift override class method inline

Tags: ios, swift, methods, overriding

I am using a scrollView inside of another view.  I want to be able to override the scrollView's touchesMoved function.  I am aware this methodology shown below is incorrect.  Can someone please inform me how to accomplish this?

```
self.scrollView.touchesMoved = func (touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("hi")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a subclass of `UIScrollView`, provide an overridden function like so

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("hi")
    }

}
```

If you are using Interface Builder, set the class of the scroll view in your UI to be the custom subclass.

[image]

Comment: This is not what I am going for.  scrollView is a variable of type UIScrollvView that exists in my ViewController.  I want to implement the scrollView.touchesmoved method in the viewDidAppear of my ViewController.swift

Comment: Override the function in a subclass of `UIScrollView` and then make the scroll view be the subclass in your UI.